Why is auto-increment not working correctly with Oracle database when using Entity Framework Core 8 and Oracle managed data access?
I'm using Entity Framework Core to create tables in an Oracle database, and I'm facing issues with auto-incrementing columns.
Although records are being inserted into the table, the auto-increment functionality does not work as expected.
enter image description here
I tried to enforce auto-increment using the ModelBuilder:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<FormOrganizationalAffectation>()
         .ToTable("ADP_FormOrganizationalAffectation");

     modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("FormOrganizationalAffectationSeq")
         .StartsAt(1)
         .IncrementsBy(1);

     modelBuilder.Entity<FormOrganizationalAffectation>()
         .Property(f => f.Id)
         .HasDefaultValueSql("FormOrganizationalAffectationSeq.NEXTVAL");
 }

but that doesn't work. I then tried setting the ID to null in my model, but it didn't work either
public class FormOrganizationalAffectation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; } = null;

    [JsonPropertyName("registrationDate")]
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("updateDate")]
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("generalInformation")]
    public GeneralInformation? GeneralInformation { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("justification")]
    public Justification? Justification { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("imagesSignatures")]
    public ImagesSignatures? ImagesSignatures { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("requisition")]
    public Requisition? Requisition { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("movement")]
    public Movement? Movement { get; set; }
}

Does anyone know what it happening ?

A sequence only guarantees that values will be unique; it does NOT guarantee that values will increase monotonically. If one process requests a value from the sequence and caches the next 20 values for that process to use and then another process requests a value from the sequence and caches the next 20 values for that other process then you will get values 1 and 21

Unrelated to your problem, but EF entity classes are not intended to be used as DTOs (as your use of [JsonPropertyName] betrays...) - this will only cause problems (and gaping security issues) down the line.

"but that doesn't work". -- There is no such thing in computing. Instead, in computing, we have this: It does not do what you expected it to do. So, state precisely what you expected and precisely what it did instead.  Was there an error message?  Well go on, don't keep it a secret.  Did it otherwise malfunction?  Don't keep that a secret either.

Thanks to everyone, your responses helped me understand what was happening.  :')

Specify "NoCache" in your sequence. By default Oracle sequences will cache 20 values, which AFAIK is associated to a connection. When the connection closes (DbContext is disposed) the cache is flushed and you lose any cached IDs. The default cache size is 20.  It may also be possible to keep the cache between connections, possibly /w Sharing, not 100% on that though.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html
"NOCACHE" notes.
